# Can I browse questions and omit a specific tag?

Tags: support

I don't play Minecraft, and most likely never will. Is there some clever lifehack I can use to omit the 'Minecraft' tag when browsing the site? In a similar fashion to how your favourite tags are highlighted.

Or is it just a matter of browsing by search? `is:question -[minecraft]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the minecraft tag to ignore.

[Go here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), scroll down and add minecraft to your ignored tags.

Comment: Make sure the radio button is set to *'Hide questions in your ignored tags'* as well